# U-Boot "bmp display <address>" does not show picture

Tags: raspberry-pi3, display, bmp, u-boot

I am using buildroot with rpi3-64 configuration; integrated is uboot 2019.07.
I did several configurations but I am unable to display a picture with `bmp display`

The screen resolution is set to 1080p with config.txt `hdmi_mode=16`

I loaded the image via `tfp <addr> <host>:/test.bmp`

Check it with `bmp info <addr>` shows the correct information about the bitmap. 
When calling `display` it simple return the input command line and does nothing

What I tried so far:

Create a full screen 1080p bitmap with 32bit also 24bit, 8bit results in an error that bitdepth do not fit to the frame buffer environment - as expected (or something like this message)
I tried lower resolution i.e. 1024*768
but had also no success with it.

I wonder if there is still any video/Fb setting to be made. Do I need special bmp setting.

Any ideas?

Comment: What was the complete command you tried to use? 'bmp display <addr> 0 0' should do the job but I have only tried on QEMU.

Comment: Yes I tried this for the 1024*768 version. I would expect an error message if this information is needed. **But I will try this again!** Further have no idea what should happen exactley? I expect the whole commandline is covered and the image is shown - with no return!?

Comment: `bmp display 100000 0 0` do not show/change anything! but `bmp info 100000` does/shows...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using buildroot, so apologies if this differs slightly. To get this working on my pi3, I had to modify u-boot/include/rpi.h to include this snippet.

```
#ifdef CONFIG_DM_VIDEO
#define CONFIG_BMP_32BPP
#endif
```

This only adds support for 32 bits/pixel, so if you need 8/16/24, use those instead.
This was tested on commit ecd4d99f654f3f7bfb96001891d69c3125e70b69 of the master branch, but I suspect it'll work on most versions.